# jquery plugin hosting as google does with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm currently linking to jquery from Google. This way I'm not hosting the file on my server.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Anyone knows of a similar service that's available for the individual jquery plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one out there yet (though some sparse plugins have their own CDN, like [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html)).

However, the jQuery team is working on this with [Media Temple](http://mediatemple.net/) (which currently hosts [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/) and other related sites)...I'm not sure how far along it is though.